# htaccess redirect question

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If no language parameter is present in the url of my site, I'd like to force a redirect to the English version of the site. My urls are as such:

http://localhost:8888/site_name/products
http://localhost:8888/site_name/products/a-nice-product

etc

If there is no "en", "fr" or "nl" after /site_name/ id like htaccess to redirect it to whatever the current url is BUT with an "en" added after /site_name/.

How would one go about this with an .htaccess file?

The current .htaccess rules are

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site_name/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mod_rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $2 !^(en|fr|nl)/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) $1/en/$2 [L,R=301]
```

---

**Edit**    Now that you’re already in `/site_name/`, try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(en|fr|nl)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.* /site_name/en/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: not working, I think a conflict with the current htaccess rules. Depending on where I paste your rules I get either nothing or internal server error.

Comment: @stef: Oh, so you’re already in `/site_name/`. You should have said that.

Comment: actually, it's also rewriting the paths to my images. How can I get it to ignore your rules if something is coming out of site_name/images/ ?

Comment: @stef: Add another condition: `RewriteCond $1 !^images$`